# Tokenizing Keywords in Lucene.Net

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, tokenize, analyzer

I am using Lucene.Net 2.9.2 and I reckon I will need to write a custom tokenizer but wanted to check in case I am missing something obvious.

The document consists of Title, Keywords and Content plus some metadata like author, date etc each stored as a field. The documents are software technical documents and may contain phrases such as '.Net', 'C++', 'C#' in the title, keywords and/or content.

I'm using the KeywordAnalyzer for the Keyword field and StandardAnalyzer for Title and Content - StopWords and LowerCase etc are necessary as the documents can be very long.

I have also written a Synonym custom filter for search as I want to search for, for example, 'C#' but also recognise 'CSharp', 'C#.Net' etc. The tokenizer has already removed the '#' from 'C#' or the '++' from C++ and therefore can be confused with, say, a 'C' language reference

My thought is that when I index Title and Content that I need to branch the tokenization depending on whether the current token is part of the keyword phrases or any of its synonyms.

Is that the best approach? Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use `WhitespaceTokenizer`, then plug in a `KeywordMarkerFilter` to mark some tokens as 'inviolable' and finally supply your own filter that would strip punctuation characters. Maybe someone with knowledge of Lucene.Net will suggest something; e.g. in Solr [`WordDelimiterFilter`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory) could be used.

Comment: Hi Artur, thanks for your answer. I believe/think that KeywordMarkerFilter was introduced to the Java API in version 3.1 - its currently not supported with .net as 2.9.2 is the latest version. However, I think what you suggest is what I was thinking i.e. emulating this in .net with a custom tokenizer. Thanks again :)

Comment: You're right I was answering the question from Lucene point of view, hope it helps nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks Artur, definitely helpful as it helps narrow down the potential options in my approach. I'll leave the question open another few days in case someone else has a viewpoint. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

The customization of tokenizer can be done with one of below mentioned classes:

1). Lucene.Net.Analysis.CharTokenizer
2). Lucene.Net.Analysis.Tokenizer

```
public class AlphaNumbericTokenizer : Lucene.Net.Analysis.CharTokenizer
{
     public AlphaNumbericTokenizer (System.IO.TextReader input) : base(input)
     {
     }
     protected override bool IsTokenChar(char c)
     {
       //TODO: Logic for identifying token or token separator
       return char.IsLetterOrDigit(c);
     }
}
```

Please refer, http://karticles.com/NoSql/lucene_custom_tokenizer.html

Comment: I went a slightly different route in solving this - I'll write it up in a blog post and post the link here with an outline of the solution. Thanks for the answer vrluckyin :)